# Basic Http Authentication

Tags: apex, webservices, security

I am writing a web service for which sends a SOAP payload as its body. In order to access the 3rd party server, I need an authenticated user. I am using Basic Http authentication for that purpose. Following is the code snippet.

```
        HTTP auth = new HTTP();
        HTTPRequest r = new HTTPRequest();
        string endpointurl='https://domainname.net/enterprise/soap?ServiceName';
        r.setEndpoint(endpointurl);
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username +':' +password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + 'EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        //String authorizationHeader = username+':'+password;
        system.debug('Encoder Value' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue));
        r.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        r.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://www.domainname.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2011/05/management#submitDocument');
        r.setMethod('POST');
```

Following code will post the http request.

```
      try
        {
            HTTPResponse authresp = auth.send(r);
            if(authresp.getStatusCode() == 200)
            { 
                system.debug('Authentication success!!!' + authresp);
            }
            else
            {system.debug('Authentication failed!!!' + authresp + authresp.getStatusCode());}    
        }catch(exception e){}
```

When I post the request, it is giving an http 500 internal server error.
Is the format of sending http request correct? Am I missing some parameters?

Comment: Have your added the remote site ? check > Your Name | Setup | Security Controls | Remote Site Settings.

Comment: Is the 500 error generated by Salesforce or by your SOAP endpoint? What are the `Content-Type` and POST body looking like?

Comment: The syntax looks right - I know with Twitter, you also have to add something in the body - is there something like that you also need to add e.g  req.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials');

Comment: @Martin Borthiry: Yes I have added remote site under security settting.

Comment: @user320: I was missing content type in the header. Now I am getting response code 200.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the 500 error is coming from your SOAP service (and not Salesforce), check:

1. what your `Content-Type` HTTP header looks like,
2. the body is set in order for the `Content-Length` header to populate,