# cURL request equivalent to HTTP request in APEX

Tags: apex, apexrest, httprequest, curl

**Scenario:** Hello, I have a cURL string which needs to be converted to Http request to be called from apex.

**Problem:** I am getting 400 Bad Request Error

**cURL:**

```
curl https://test.sagepay.com/api/v1/merchant-session-keys \
-u "integrationKey:integrationPassword"  \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-X POST \
-d '{ 
    "vendorName": "testVendor" 
}'
```

**Apex Http Request**

```
req.setEndpoint('https://test.sagepay.com/api/v1/merchant-session-keys');

req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setBody('vendorName:testVendor');

Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(integrationKey +':' +IntegrationPassword);
String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + 'EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);

req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
```

Note: A similar question has already been posted previously: [link here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82507/how-to-convert-below-curl-into-http-request-type)

Comment: Are you sending JSON data to server?

Answer (score 2):

Try this ;)

```
req.setBody('{"vendorName":"testVendor"}');
```

Send valid JSON data to server; As server also saying `400 Bad Request Error`;

Comment: This is the correct answer, and it worked. Thanks itzmukeshy7. Also let me know how to mark it as answer, because I cannot add a comment. Mansoor

Comment: @Mansoor did you log in using the same account ?

Comment: @Mansoor You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). Find more here [Accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line in your code.

```
req.setBody('vendorName=testVendor');
```

Instead of:

```
req.setBody('vendorName:testVendor');
```