# Webservice - Salesforce call “BASIC authenticate Pre-emptively” service

Tags: apex, webservices

Is anybody have example for salesforce call webservice with BASIC authenticate Pre-emptively?
I have scenario to invoke webservice BASIC. Using username password authentication.
And need to parse some field parameter. The service is used to create record in back end when new record created in salesforce.

my code is:

```
        HTTP auth = new HTTP();
        String username = 'domain\\username';
        String password = 'password!';
        HTTPRequest r = new HTTPRequest();
        string endpointurl='myEndPointHTTP';
        r.setEndpoint(endpointurl);
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username +':' +password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        system.debug('Encoder Value' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue));
        r.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        r.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/SalesForce:UPSERTContact');
        r.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');

        r.setMethod('POST');

         try
        {
            HTTPResponse authresp = auth.send(r);
            if(authresp.getStatusCode() == 200)
            { 
                system.debug('Authentication success!!!' + authresp);
            }
            else
            {system.debug('Authentication failed!!!' + authresp + authresp.getStatusCode());}    
        }catch(exception e)'
```

===================================================================

my to pass parameter to the webservice?
and how to determine 'Content-Length' in header ?

Comment: check this out http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/11015/18731

Comment: Hi @Ratan , i tried the example before. but i got 'Authentication failed!!!System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Gateway, StatusCode=502]'.

Comment: Can you just add your code. what you have tried so far. let me take a look ?

Comment: hi @Ratan, how to pass parameter to the webservice? 
and how to determine 'Content-Length' in header ?

Comment: Kinux... check this code for callout https://gist.github.com/RatanPaul/255dd68cc8b2164bb5e6acd216e82cbc.js"

Comment: Kinux.. [did you get a chance to look into my answer?

Comment: @Ratan, i seen the post. but still dont understant.
for header section is already clear. ican get respond from the targeted server.
the question now is how for the body section to pass the field value required by the service.

Comment: what you didn't understand ?